# Exception thrown: read access violation **this**

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort through two separate arrays containing objects passed to functions in order to find the highest salary. I thought I had it figured out, but then I get the error given below:
"Exception thrown: read access violation. **this** was 0x12963854."
I feel like this could be a simple fix and I am just overlooking it. This is all written in c++ using the newest version of visual studios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 main bugs in your code, in order of appearance:

- `highest` and `otherHighest` are not initialized
- As pointed out by Kim Nyholm the salaries are used as indexes
- Then `highest` and `otherHighest` are used as salaries instead of indexes

```
// Initialized as index of the first element
int highest = 0;
int otherHighest = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    if (baseballArray[highest].getSalary() < baseballArray[i].getSalary())
        highest = i; // Stores the index

    if (basketballArray[otherHighest].getSalary() < basketballArray[i].getSalary())
         otherHighest = i; // Stores the index
}

// Compares the salaries
if (baseballArray[highest].getSalary() > basketballArray[otherHighest].getSalary())
    baseballArray[highest].printStats();
else if (basketballArray[otherHighest].getSalary() > baseballArray[highest].getSalary())
    basketballArray[otherHighest].printStats();
else // if (baseballArray[highest].getSalary() == basketballArray[otherHighest].getSalary())
    cout << "error";
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I originally had my code similar to what you have written above and then went a completely different way with it. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer or Kim's helped you, you can accept one

Answer (score 2):

You are wrongly using the salaries `highest` and `otherHighest` as indexes into the arrays `baseballArray` and `basketballArray`!

Comment: Also highest and otherHighest are not initialized!